# Where is initial snapshot of EC2 volume?

Tags: aws-ec2

When I launch EC2 (Amazon Linux) instance, attached volume shows snapshot id in details pane. That snapshot ID is not shown in Snapshots section.
What is the logic/reasining behind "default" snapshot?
Note: I never created a snapshot of instance. It is brand new instance and purpose was to see snapshot actions?
How do I use/refer to that snapshot?

Edit:
`ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=volume-id,Values=[vol-01234567890]"` returns empty array.

```json
{
    "Snapshots": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot is not shown because by default, snapshot page shows 'Owned by ne'. When I selected 'Public snapshots', I was able to find it. It is owned by 137112412989. I suppose it is Amazon. Snapshot info

```json
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids snap-0200ee85b16848129
{
    "Snapshots": [
        {
            "Description": "",
            "Encrypted": false,
            "OwnerId": "137112412989",
            "Progress": "100%",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-0200ee85b16848129",
            "StartTime": "2021-12-01T20:02:15.412000+00:00",
            "State": "completed",
            "VolumeId": "vol-ffffffff",
            "VolumeSize": 8,
            "OwnerAlias": "amazon"
        }
    ]
}
```